# How to read row, class

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to read row on datagrid wpf, but one column is a class.

```
public partial class Sales
{

    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string NrOrder { get; set; }

    public LinesSales AllLinesSales { get; set; }
}

public partial class LinesSales
{
    public string Product { get; set; }

    public string NameProd { get; set; }

    public douyble Qtd { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
Type tiposSales = typeof(Sales);
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties =
             tiposSales.GetProperties();
System.Data.DataTable dtSales  = new System.Data.DataTable();

foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{
    dtSales.Columns.Add(pi.Name); 
}
...
foreach (Sales pSal in fileSales)
{
    listaSales.Add(pSal);

}

datagrid_ListSales.ItemsSource = listaSales;
```

...

```
//When clicked row...
private void datagrid_ListSales_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    LinesSales l_ade = 
        (LinesSales)((datagrid_ListSales.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView)
            .Row["AllLinesSales"]); <---error

//I want read all items subclass LinesSales:  
txt_Product = l_ade.Product.ToString();

...
```

Cannot cast LinesSales as System.String.

How to read class?

Regards

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do.  If you just want the backing data for the row that was selected, why are you casting the SelectedItem to the DataRowView?  Is the item source for the data grid is a list of Sales, you should be able to cast it to a Sales object

Comment: Because I needed to add a virtual column

Comment: That is a new term for me with respect to the data grid. I am familiar with setting the enable virtual rows property, but nothing around a virtual column.  What is a virtual column?